# Search a date between group of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

My table name is client_details and my date field contain group of dates like

```
03/03/2015,04/13/2015,05/11/2015,06/08/2015,09/04/...
03/18/2015,04/28/2015,05/26/2015,06/23/2015,09/19/...
03/20/2015,04/30/2015,05/28/2015,06/25/2015,09/21/...
03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/...
03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/...
03/06/2015,04/16/2015,05/14/2015,06/11/2015,09/07/...
03/13/2015,04/23/2015,05/21/2015,06/18/2015,09/14/...
04/16/2015,05/27/2015,06/24/2015,07/22/2015,10/18/...
03/03/2015,04/13/2015,05/11/2015,06/08/2015,09/04/...
03/04/2015,04/14/2015,05/12/2015,06/09/2015,09/05/...
03/19/2015,04/29/2015,05/27/2015,06/24/2015,09/20/...
```

I want to search a date between '03/26/2015' and '05/12/2015'.How can i write the query?

Comment: Do you mean you are storing dates as a comma separated list in a single column?

Comment: @GarethD yes i stored like that

Comment: **WHY?** The very nature of a relational database is that you do not need to store data like this, you create a new table with a one to many relationship and store one date per row in a column with a datetime type. You then have a very simple query that can use indexes properly and doesn't require conversions, or expensive split operations. I have put an example schema, and query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27b9a/1) - rather than trying to workaround your design I would suggest you change it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE `DateField` BETWEEN '03/26/2015' AND '05/12/2015';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf738/2)

**EDIT:-**

So your comments show that you are storing the dates by seperating them with comma. I would seriosuly discourage that practise and recommend you to change the design of your table. That is a poor way of storing the dates.

**Reasons:**

1. It will lead you to troubles everytime you want to use date functions.
2. It is not performance effective.

**Alternate Solutions:**

1. Change the design of your table.
2. Create a seperate table which stores the dates corresponding to a user_id and then join this table with your client_details table using the user_id and get the date which you want.

Comment: @Fiona:- What it is resulting?

Comment: @Fiona:- Added a fiddle to my answer. As per me it is working as per your expected result. Do let me know what is missing?

Comment: The "date field" seems to contain lots of comma separated dates.

Comment: In the above dates  each datefield contain one date between '03/26/2015' AND '05/12/2015' .Then i want to result  all records

Comment: @Fiona, does the datefield contain one or several dates?

Comment: 03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/...
03/26/2015,05/06/2015,06/03/2015,07/01/2015,09/27/... 04/16/2015,05/27/2015,06/24/2015,07/22/2015,10/18/... this only resulting

Comment: @Fiona:- Why are you storing the dates like this?

Comment: @Rahul each datefield records belonging to each  user

Comment: @Fiona:- I think you can store them in different rows as that would help you in many ways including creating queries like this. The above way of storing the dates in columns is not recommended and may put you in deep trouble in future. Its just a sggestion.

Comment: @Fiona:- And if you dont want (which I would seriosuly discourage) to put them in different rows then I would recommend you to create a function which splits the dates and puts them into a temporary table. And then you can join the temp table with your main table using the user_id and use the above logic.

Comment: @Rahul Actually i don't know how much column will come.its a  genering date and stored into a one field.

Comment: @Fiona:- I tried to put an alternate solution. I dont think anyone here will encourage you with the way you are proceeding.